# How can I use Closures in Closures, without creating an infinite loop?

Tags: swift, closures

This is my code

fetchCurrentUser() function calls 'observeCurrentUserFromDisk' first, then if its not on disk then call 'observeCurrentUserToDisk'(firebase), how can I call again  'observeCurrentUserFromDisk' after calling 'observeCurrentUserToDisk' to return the result from 'observeCurrentUserFromDisk' to the function(fetchCurrentUser) that first called  'observeCurrentUserFromDisk' using closures, trying to maintain D.R.Y Thank you.

```
func fetchCurrentUser() {
        // I don't want to call these two functions each time
        Api.User.observeCurrentUserFromDisk(onSuccess: { (user) in
            
            self.emailLabel.text = user.email
            
            if let profileUrl = URL(string: user.profileImageUrl!) {
                self.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: profileUrl)
            }
        }) {
            Api.User.observeCurrentUserToDisk(onSuccess: {
                self.fetchCurrentUser()
            }) { (error) in
                ProgressHUD.showError(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func observeCurrentUserToDisk(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
        
        guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else { return }
        
        Config.REF_USERS.child(currentUser).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                
                let user = UserModel.transformUser(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
                
                Api.Realm.writeUserToDisk(user)
                onSuccess()
            }
        })
    }
    
    func observeCurrentUserFromDisk(onSuccess: @escaping (RealmUser) -> Void, onError: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        guard let uid = Api.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid else { return }
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", uid)
        var users: Results<RealmUser>!
        users = usersOnDisk.objects(RealmUser.self).filter(predicate)
        
        if let index = users.index(matching: predicate) {
            let user = users[index]
            
            onSuccess(user)
        } else {
            onError()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only reason why this could end up in an infinite loop is the toDisk function is giving you a false positive i.e. it's reporting it succeeded when it actually did not. Isolate this on a separate function for testing purpose. First call observeCurrentUserToDisk and on its success block call observeCurrentUserFromDisk. I'm guessing observeCurrentUserFromDisk is going to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem calling a function inside itself - it's called a recursion, and so long as you have a stop condition, this isn't going be infinite.

In your case, somewhere you're making the determination that you need to perform `observeCurrentUserToDisk` - presumably, if you didn't, then the function would be done. That is your stop condition.

Furthermore, since `fetchCurrentUser` is async and you're going to call it and need to act on its results, add completion (`onSuccess` and `onError`) handlers to it as well.

Here's a general idea:

```
func fetchCurrentUser(onSuccess: @escaping (RealmUser) -> Void, 
                      onError: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

   observeCurrentUserFromDisk(
      onSuccess: onSuccess,
      onError: {
          observeCurrentUserToDisk(
             onSuccess: {
                // start recursive call, and in the next iteration this shouldn't 
                // end in onError of observeCurrentUserFromDisk. 
                // Though, if it's a possibility, you might want to limit
                // the number of tries before failing
                fetchCurrentUser(onSuccess: onSuccess) 
             },
             onError: onError)
      }
}
```

You can use `fetchCurrentUser`'s completion handler to do what you needed:

```
fetchCurrentUser(
   onSuccess: { user in
      self.emailLabel.text = user.email
            
      if let profileUrl = URL(string: user.profileImageUrl!) {
         self.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: profileUrl)
      }
   }, 
   onError: {
      // handle the error case
   })
```

Comment: thank you very much this is what I needed! life saver

Answer (score 0):

You can capture your closures in vars and then reference that in another closure. For example:

```
var onFetch = { a in print(a) }

var saveUsers = { b in 
    if b {
        onFetch()
    }
}
```